Pycharm Frames incomplete and Unhelpful
I suspect this is a straightforward problem but I haven't been able to find the solution elsewhere. I'm using the JetBrains PyCharm Debugger and when the program hits an exception, the debugger shows this very unhelpful frame stack.
The program is not multithreaded, and (unsurprisingly) the "MainThread" combo box does not provide any alternative threads.
I would like the debugger to show the same frames as the console traceback. In the case of my example, that is
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/josh/pycharm-2024.1.1/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 2236, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/josh/pycharm-2024.1.1/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 2218, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/josh/pycharm-2024.1.1/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1528, in run
    return self._exec(is_module, entry_point_fn, module_name, file, globals, locals)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/josh/pycharm-2024.1.1/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1535, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/josh/pycharm-2024.1.1/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/home/josh/.config/JetBrains/PyCharm2024.1/scratches/scratch.py", line 3, in <module>
    e.do_setup()
  File "/home/josh/pypatchy/pypatchy/patchy/simulation_ensemble.py", line 1270, in do_setup
    self.write_setup_files(sim, stage)
  File "/home/josh/pypatchy/pypatchy/patchy/simulation_ensemble.py", line 1376, in write_setup_files
    stage.build_input()
  File "/home/josh/pypatchy/pypatchy/patchy/stage.py", line 182, in build_input
    for pv in self.getctxt().iter_params(self.spec(), self):
  File "/home/josh/pypatchy/pypatchy/patchy/simulation_ensemble.py", line 649, in iter_params
    if pv not in pvs:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: unhashable type: 'ParameterValue'
python-BaseException

